# Find specific link in html doc c# using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse an HTML document in order to retrieve a specific link within the page. I know this may not be the best way, but I'm trying to find the HTML node I need by its inner text. However, there are two instances in the HTML where this occurs: the footer and the navigation bar. I need the link from the navigation bar. The "footer" in the HTML comes first. Here is my code:

```
    public string findCollegeURL(string catalog, string college)
    {
        //Find college
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(catalog);
        var root = doc.DocumentNode;
        var htmlNodes = root.DescendantsAndSelf();

        // Search through fetched html nodes for relevant information
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlNodes) {
            string linkName = node.InnerText;
            if (linkName == colleges[college] && counter == 0)
            {
                counter++;
                continue;
            }  
            else if(linkName == colleges[college] && counter == 1)
            {
                string targetURL = node.Attributes["href"].Value; //"found it!"; //
                return targetURL;
            }/* */
        }

        return "DID NOT WORK";
    }
```

The program is entering into the if else statement, but when attempting to retrieve the link, I get a NullReferenceException. **Why is that? How can I retrieve the link I need?**

Here is the code in the HTML doc that I'm trying to access:

```
    <tr class>
       <td id="acalog-navigation">
           <div class="n2_links" id="gateway-nav-current">...</div>
           <div class="n2_links">...</div>
           <div class="n2_links">...</div>
           <div class="n2_links">...</div>
           <div class="n2_links">...</div>
              <a href="/content.php?catoid=10&navoid=1210" class"navbar" tabindex="119">College of Science</a> ==$0
           </div>
```

**This is the link that I want: /content.php?catoid=10&navoid=1210**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find using XPath easier to use instead of writing a lot of code

```
var link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[text()='College of Science']")
              .Attributes["href"].Value;
```

If you have 2 links with the same text, to select the 2nd one

```
var link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("(//a[text()='College of Science'])[2]")
              .Attributes["href"].Value;
```

The *Linq* version of it

```
var links = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
               .Where(a => a.InnerText == "College of Science")
               .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: I get an error with that. 'HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'SelectSingleNode'

Comment: @AndreaS. Which version of it do you use? What is your environment?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: @AndreaS. I meant your target, for windows? wp10? Xpath is not available for windows phone... But I also  added a *linqy* way for it...